# Unexpected results with "TrimEnd()" ... results are randomly too greedy

Tags: c#, string, .net-3.5, trim

I'm getting inconsistent results with TrimEnd() under .NET 3.5.  TrimEnd seems so simple to use, is there something I'm doing wrong here or is this a bug

**Success case**

```
  var foundvalue = "hosted.local.chatter.com";
  Console.WriteLine(foundvalue.TrimEnd(".chatter.com".ToCharArray()));
  // Result is "hosted.local" which is expected.
```

**Failure case**

```
 var foundvalue = "hosted.local.chattermailcom";
 Console.WriteLine(foundvalue.TrimEnd(".chattermailcom".ToCharArray()));
 // Result is "hosted" which is incorrect
```

Comment: Wow... zero upvotes.  I guess everyone knew this except me!  This is what happens when you are self-taught (with much reading on S.O. )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could write your own method for that:

```
public static class Extensions
{
  public static string RemoveEnd(this string strBefore, string substringToRemove)
  {
    if (!strBefore.EndsWith(substringToRemove))
      return strBefore;

    return strBefore.Remove(strBefore.Length - substringToRemove.Length);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You aren't removing the exact string, `".chattermailcom"` from the end, you're removing each of the characters, '.', 'c', 'a', 't', 'e', 'r', etc. from the end of the string.  `".chattermailcom"` happens to have all of the letters in `local`, but `".chatter.com"` doesn't (the key letter there being the `l`).

If you want to remove the entire string from the end consider using `EndsWith` to do the check, and then `substring` if it's true.

You could also consider avoiding the string manipulation entirely and using the URI class; it could parse the entire URL for you and return the various components.

Answer (score 6):

As per [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx), `TrimEnd` removes all characters from the end of the string which are in the array you've passed. For the second case, the "d" is not part of the array so the method will stop here.

Answer (score 2):

Why does that surprise you? TrimEnd takes an array of characters to remove from the end. You tell it to remove all '.', 'c', 'h', 'a', 't' and so on.. And exactly why you tell it to remove it all characters within the string ".local.", they will be removed. Please read again what TrimEnd() does.

Answer (score 1):

TrimEnd is not designed to strip a string off. The word "local" contains all characters that are in your trimEnd chars ("chattermailcom" -> includes l, o, c, a, and l). You are getting expected behavior of trimEnd.

[String.TrimEnd Method (MSDN):](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx)

> The TrimEnd method removes from the current string all trailing
>   characters that are in the trimChars parameter. The trim operation
>   stops when the first character that is not in trimChars is encountered
>   at the end of the string. For example, if the current string is
>   "123abc456xyz789" and trimChars contains the digits from "1" through
>   "9", the TrimEnd method returns "123abc456xyz".